# how to mount secret in openshift with uid:gid set correctly

Tags: postgresql, ssl, kubernetes, openshift

I'm using this `Dockerfile` to deploy it on openshift. - https://github.com/sclorg/postgresql-container/tree/master/9.5

It works fine, until I enabled `ssl=on` and injected the `server.crt` and `server.key` file into the postgres pod via volume mount option.

Secret is created like

```
$ oc secret new postgres-secrets \
  server.key=postgres/server.key \
  server.crt=postgres/server.crt \
  root-ca.crt=ca-cert
```

The volume is created as bellow and attached to the given `BuidlConfig` of postgres.

```
$ oc volume dc/postgres \
  --add --type=secret \
  --secret-name=postgres-secrets \
  --default-mode=0600 \
 -m /var/lib/pgdata/data/secrets/secrets/
```

Problem is the mounted files of `secret.crt` and `secret.key` files is owned by `root` user, but `postgres` expect it should be owned by the `postgres` user. Because of that the postgres server won't come up and says this error.

> waiting for server to start....FATAL:  could not load server
>   certificate file "/var/lib/pgdata/data/secrets/secrets/server.crt":
>   Permission denied  stopped waiting pg_ctl: could not start server

How we can insert a volume and update the `uid:guid` of the files in it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like this is not trivial, as it requires to set Volume Security Context so all the containers in the pod are run as a certain user https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.1/install_config/persistent_storage/pod_security_context.html

In the Kubernetes projects, this is something that is still under discussion https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/2630, but seems that you may have to use Security Contexts and PodSecurityPolicies in order to make it work.

I think the easiest option (without using the above) would be to use a container entrypoint that, before actually executing PostgreSQL, it chowns the files to the proper user (postgres in this case).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually I was also thinking the same way as your second workaround. The container entry point is now updated to take the secret files mounted via openshit ( via ENV ) and copy to another location, so the file permission issue won't come again. Good that you pointed out the SCC methods, need to read more on it. Thanks Javier.